# Ярославна или Ярославовна?

Tags: имена-собственные

Раньше, как я понимаю, женские отчества читались иначе — пример: Анна Ярославна. Сейчас мы бы сказали Ярославовна. Откуда взялось это усложнение, если принято считать, что язык развивается в сторону упрощения? Или она была все-таки Ярославовна, но "-ов" выбросили для краткости в хрониках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть в русском языке такое явление, как гаплология: если слог в результате стыка морфем повторяется дважды, то один из этих слогов исчезает. Так, например, из корня -розов- и суффикса -оват-, получилось не "розововатый",а "розоватый".

"Ярославна" подверглась тому же самому явлению (Яросла**въвъ**на стала Яросла**въ**на), а писали раньше так же, как произносили. Сейчас, с развитием грамотности, появилась обратная тенденция.

Кстати, "Ярославна" до сих пор является нормой фонетического произношения отчества "Ярославовна".

Comment: >"Ярославъвъна"   
  
Это в цитатник. Простите, но минус за полное незнание предмета.
1. "на" уже само по себе несет притяжательность, как "ич" в мужском случае. Сочетание с "ов" невозсожно.
2. Прияжательный суффикс "-овъ", не "-ъвъ".

Comment: 1. Во II склонении суффикс -ич и -на, в I -ов, ставший впоследствии --ович, -овна.

2. Слово Ярославъвъна никогда так не писалась, хотя бы по той причине, что к моменту появления письменности, такого слова уже не было. Однако учитывая, что ударение падало бы на корень, примерно так бы и произносилось. Полностью воспроизводить древнерусское написание у меня и в мыслях не было, важнее показать схожесть.

 В "розо**вова**тый"  не подскажете где происходит граница "учекаемого" слога? Случайно не в том же самом месте, что и у Ярославовны? Да и схожесть [ʌ] и [А] с [Ъ] и [О] примерно одного уровня.

Answer (score 4):

> Раньше, как я понимаю, женские отчества читались иначе — пример: Анна Ярославна. Сейчас мы бы сказали Ярославовна. Откуда взялось это усложнение?

Усложнение - от чтения. Не только в данном случае. Нормативно было произносить и Николавна вместо Николаевна. Может, и сейчас нормативно. Хотя на практике у нас я произношение Николавна слышала только от преподавателя университета, ученицы Аванесова. Ну еще от некоторых преподавателей школьных. Чтение влияет на произношение многих слов. Например, сочетание ЧН  почти перестало произноситься как ШН. А еще, выполняя задания с девятиклассниками по фонетике, я заметила, что они часто не замечают непроизносимый согласный. Некоторые считают, что правильно произнести  именно так, как написано.

Answer (score 2):

Об образовании отчеств можно прочитать в книге "УДИВИТЕЛЬНАЯ ЭТИМОЛОГИЯ"
Анатолия Павловича Пасхалова. А по Вашему конкретному вопросу ответ таков:
 **если имя оканчивается на твёрдый согласный** (*кроме ж, ш, ч, щ, ц*), **добавляется -ович / овна** : Ярослав + ович/-овна, Александр + ович/овна, Иван + ович/овна, Гамзат + ович/овна, Карл + ович/овна. Исходя из этого правила - Анна Ярославовна (Станиславовна и т. д.)

Comment: А что это умная книга говорит об обращзовании отчеств Ярославич, Ярославна и подобных, которые фиксируются в словарях русских имен?

Comment: В данном случае вы, @Соан, не правы. Имена со "-слав" вариативны. Возможно как Ярославич, так и Ярославович. См. пункт 336 данной [ссылки](http://rusgram.narod.ru/328-379.html)

Comment: Марк Из, моя ошибка лишь в том, что я не объяснила вариант на -ич (Ярославич), отнеся эту форму к разговорной речи. Даже сейчас, просмотрев Вашу ссылку,  уверена (хотя я чту грам. правила), что отчества со "-слав" на морф -ич - это разговорный вариант; для меня, хоть и длинно выговаривается, но Ярославович нормативно.

Comment: @Соан, форма на -ич, более древняя ("Правда Ярославичей"), и согласен, что сейчас она уже устаревающая, причины её появления описаны в моём ответе и в комментарии к ответу behemothus. Но всё-таки категорично утверждать, что нормативно только -ович я бы не стал. Скажем, если у меня будет дочь, то отчество у неё точно будет Владиславна, а не "гавкающее" Владиславовна. :-)

Comment: Я не категорична, просто один из вариантов показался мне устаревшим и малоупотребляемым.  Каждый вправе выбирать то, что ближе, привычнее, понятнее.

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Не сказали бы "Ярославовна".
Ярославна - нормативный вариант отчества от Ярослав.
Варианты "Ярославович, Ярославовна", как и подобные от Ростислав, Святослав и др. приводятся в словарях (обычно - наряду с исходными), но реально они вторичны и малоупотребительны.

Гаплология тут, думается, рядом не лежала (Марк Из вообще её роль несколько преувеличивает и не со всем правильно трактует), поскольку повторения слогов нет, здесь исчезновение суффикса явление того же порядка, что "исчезновение" -ов в Никитич, Фомич и т.д. Элементарное упрощение под действием длины слова. 
Ярославович, Ярославовна могло бы образоваться только от "Ярославов", но такое русскому языку не свойственно (сравните Ярославль вместо Ярославов, Станистав вместо Станистлавов - старое название Ивано-Франковска и даже Ярославин как притяжательное). ).

Comment: 1. Никита, Фома и пр., заканчивающиеся на "-а" - это II склонение, и словообразование там происходит другим способом, чем у существительных I, как "Ярослав" (сравни синиц**ын**, но сокол**ов**).  
2. "Ярославов",, так как гаплология уже не влияет. современному языку вполне свойственно, см. Ярославов Вал в Киеве или Ярославово Дворище в В. Новгороде, отчество Ярославович.  
3. Повторения слогов нет в современном русском, а в древнерусском произносилось бы "Яросла**въвъ**". Для избежания повторений слогов и использовали протетическую -л- или несвойственное склонение (Пров**ич**, Яков**л**евич).

Comment: 1. Да. А я что против?
2. Переведи (С). Я же о от и говорю, что от "Ярослав" и прочих славов прлуктивным было другое притяжательно образование на "-ль", откуда Ярославль и другие подобные топонимы. 
3. Точную дату падения редуцированных не назовете? И откуда там ер в первом случае? Притяжательный суффикс -овъ, не -ъвъ.

Comment: 1. Тогда какой смысл смешивать 2 разных склонения и делать из этого выводы?
2. Всё верно. Только почему Ярославич, но Константинович это не объясняет, второе явно подлиннее будет. Пример с сыновьями Прова и Якова я привёл выше.
3. Цитирую себя "**произносилось** бы "Ярославъвъ"", в данном случае меня интересовала фонетика, а не грамматика.